# Какой python web framework выбрать, чтобы «положил index.html, папочки css, js в htdocs» и все сразу заработало?

Tags: python, python-2.x, flask

Я попытался оформить вопрос как можно более просто и при этом чтобы он на 100% отразил желаемый результат.

Человеку необходимо, чтобы было все как с Apache: "положил index.html, папочки css, js в htdocs (просто landing page, к слову)" и все сразу заработало, без необходимости вносить правки. Такое возможно?
python 2 (3, к сожалению, нет)

Comment: Зачем для указанной функциональности нужен Питон. Что мешает продолжать apache использовать?

Comment: Привет,  jfs. Ответ на ваш вопрос прост: такова задача.

Comment: Вы понимаете что веб сервер и веб framework это разные понятия?

Comment: jfs. Да, конечно.

Comment: Если понимаете, тогда зачем вам framework для статического сайта?

Comment: jfs, чтобы человек смог хоть какой-то обработчик повесить на форму. Что ли. Вот оно, вот оно - php головного мозга. Потому что я не до конца соображаю, понимаете.

Comment: Если вы хотите и формы динамически обрабатывать на сервере, тогда отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте эту ключевую информацию. Если сможете ещё требования вспомнить, то их также упомяните.

Comment: Если очень нужно используйте обработку html как python cgi, но зачем? ). Опишите логику работы, тогда кто-то сможет сказать что делать. К тому же как на python почту отправить знаете? Если не знаете, то возьмите php, он лучше подойдет под задачу.

Comment: jfs, тогда придется вопрос полностью изменить. Я тут прикинул, действительно от старого ничего не останется. Может, тогда этот вопрос удалить?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что автор получил ответ на вопрос, но в комментариях спрашивает уже по сути другой вопрос. Этот следует закрыть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял - нужен веб-сервер, который публикует директорию.

Возьмите [стандартный модуль http сервера](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html). Для того чтобы опубликовать директорию нужно выполнить:

```
cd $workdir
python2.7 -m SimpleHTTPServer $port
```

Если нужна настройка маршрутов и шаблоны, POST-запросы, авторизация или работа с БД - используйте Flask, CherryPy, или Django.

Comment: Там просто landing page. Кстати, интересно, как человек еще форму обрабатывать тогда будет.

Comment: Я бы взял Flask и использовал Flask-RESTful, но проще - описать обработчик через if request.method == "POST": response для /index

Answer (score 0):

Вы смотрели в сторону [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/)?

> What Python version can I use with Django?
>
> Django version > Python versions
>
> 1.8 > 2.7, 3.2 (until the end of 2016), 3.3, 3.4, 3.5
>
> 1.9,1.10 > 2.7, 3.4, 3.5
>
> 1.11 >2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6
>
> 2.0 > 3.5+

django содержит встроенный веб-сервер. По сылочке выше можно даже не читать, просто сделайте две команды из синих блоков и все заработает.

Comment: 1. Создал тестовый проект командой: sudo django-admin startproject myproject
2. Запустил сервер командой: python manage.py runserver 8080
3. Тестовая страница открывается, все работает, ок.
Вопрос: как теперь подсунуть серверу файл index.html и папки css, js? :)

Comment: @Noneme, это уже по сути другой вопрос, который стоит оформить отдельно.